# select/update where all childs status = 0

Tags: mysql

I have the table `categories`:

```
categories_id | categories_status | parent_id
     1                  1               0
     2                  1               0
     3                  0               1
     4                  0               2
     5                  1               1
     6                  0               2
```

How can i select and update the status of the categories where all child categories having status = 0 (in this example it's just the categories_id 2)? I need to integrate this in PHP.

Thanks in advance,

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update categories,
(
  select parent_id, sum(categories_status) as cnt
  from categories
  where parent_id!=0
  group by parent_id
  having cnt=0 
) as child_cat
set ? = ?   /* what do you want to update? */
where categories.categories_id=child_cat.parent_id
```

Likely you don't have to use PHP, a SQL will do.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this on MSSQL so the syntax may be a little different, but I believe this is what you are after:

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE parent_id NOT IN
(
    SELECT parent_id
    FROM <table_name>
    WHERE categories_status = 1
    GROUP BY parent_id
)
```

Update Query:

```
UPDATE <table_name>
SET categories_status = 1
WHERE parent_id NOT IN 
(
    SELECT parent_id
    FROM <table_name>
    WHERE categories_status = 1
    GROUP BY parent_id
)
```

The idea is to isolate the parent_ids you would like to exclude from your base query. You can achieve that using a sub-query.